# Match names and publication titles in academic listings with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying a regex to match citation title.

This is my regex:

```
(?!([Á-ÝA-Z\s\-])*?(\.|;|,)\s*)([^;]+?\.\s)
```

The title is highlighted in bold in the following examples:

---

BENVENISTE, É. **Problemas de linguística geral.** São Paulo: Ed. Nacional; EDUSP, 1976. Volume I.

BERNERS-LEE, T. **Semantic Web Concepts.** 2005a. Disponível em: http://www.w3.org/2005/Talks/0517-boit-tbl. Acesso em: 25 set. 2014

BERNERS-LEE, T. **Web for real people.** 2005b. Disponível em . Acesso em: 25 set. 2014.

BERNERS-LEE, T.; CAILLIAU, R. **WorldWideWeb: Proposal for a HyperText Project.** 1990. Disponível em: < http://www.w3.org/Proposal.html >. Acesso em: 13 out. 2014.

BERNERS-LEE, T.; HENDLER, J.; LASSILA, O. **The semantic web: a new form of web content that is meaningful to computers will unleash a revolution of new possibilities.** New York: Scientific American, 2001. Disponível em: http://www.sciam.com/2001/050lissue/0501berners-lee.html. Acesso em: 13 out. 2014.

BLAIR, D. C. **Information Retrieval and the Philosophy of Language.** Annual Review of Information Science and Tecchnology, v. 37, pp. 3-50, Medford, 2003.

BLAIR, D. C. **Wittgenstein, Language and Information: Back to the Rough Ground!** Dordrecht: Springer, 2006.

BONFIM, M. E. **Recuperação de Documentos Texto Usando Um Modelo Probabilístico Estendido.** Piracicaba: UNIMEP, 2006. 131 f.  Dissertação (Mestrado em Ciência da Computação).  Mestrado em Ciência da Computação. Universidade Metodista de Piracicaba, 2006.

BORLUND, P. **The Concept of Relevance in IR.** Journal of the American Society for Information Science and Technology, v.54, p. 913-925, 2003.

BORST, W. N. **Construction of engineering ontologies.** Tese (Doutorado em Information and Knowledge Systems). University of Tweenty – Centre for Telematica and Information Technology, Enschede, Nederland, 1997.

BOUNDLESS. **Boundless Psychology.** 201X. Disponível em < https://www.boundless.com/psychology/textbooks/boundless-psychology-textbook/ > Acesso em: 13 ago. 2014.

BRATT, S. **Semantic Web, and Other Technologies to Watch.** 2008. Disponível em < http://www.w3.org/2008/Talks/1009-bratt-W3CSemTech/Overview.html > Acesso em: 13 ago. 2014.

---

All strings to test can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/1

My question: What modifications do I have to make to match only the title? I am trying to match only until the first dot but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your regex a little for the output you want

```
^.*?(?!(?:[Á-ÝA-Z\s\-])*?(?:\.|;|,)\s*)([^;]+?(?:\.|\!)\s).*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/3),,,  in which I added anchors(`^ and $`) for the one match a line and I changed parenthesis groups to `non-capturing groups` except the one what you want capture for the output.

```
([^;]+?(?:\.|\!)\s)
```

in this capturing `group 1` (or `\1`), I added the possibility that the capturing target string may end with `!` character.

Replace matches with `\1` for your output view.

```
Problemas de linguística geral. 
Semantic Web Concepts. 
Web for real people. 
WorldWideWeb: Proposal for a HyperText Project. 
The semantic web: a new form of web content that is meaningful to computers will unleash a revolution of new possibilities. 
Information Retrieval and the Philosophy of Language. 
Wittgenstein, Language and Information: Back to the Rough Ground! 
Recuperação de Documentos Texto Usando Um Modelo Probabilístico Estendido. 
The Concept of Relevance in IR. 
Construction of engineering ontologies. 
Boundless Psychology. 
Semantic Web, and Other Technologies to Watch.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try and *(1)* match the name, *(2)* then the title, since the end of the name marks the beginning of the title. The various ways that names occur can be categorized. I would start by noting that `^[Á-ÝA-Z-]+` catches the first word in each name on each line.

**Matching the name.**

- Two ("ARISTÓTELES.", "BOUNDLESS.") end with a period after the first word.

  So `^[Á-ÝA-Z-]+\.` could work for those.
- One ("BRITISH LIBRARY.") has multiple words.

  So `^[Á-ÝA-Z-][Á-ÝA-Z\s-]+\.` would include it.
- Two ("ASSOCIAÇÃO BRASILEIRA DE NORMAS TÉCNICAS (ABNT).", "INTERNATIONAL ORGANIZATION FOR STANDARDIZATION (ISO).") have multiple words and parentheses.

  So `^[Á-ÝA-Z-][Á-ÝA-Z()\s-]+\.` would include them.
- Most (e.g. "ARMENGAUD, F.", "BUNGE, M.") are names, comma, space, initial, period.

  If we simply add `,` to the character group like we did for `(` and `)`, we neglect to match the ones with two initials fully (e.g. "BLAIR, D. C."). We can't include `.` in the character group, since we relied on the period as our separator between name and title. So we have to match the periods after initials more specifically.

  So `^[Á-ÝA-Z-][Á-ÝA-Z\s()-]+(?:\.|, [Á-ÝA-Z-]\.)` would include them.
- Then there were the cases with multiple initials.

  So `^[Á-ÝA-Z-][Á-ÝA-Z\s()-]+(?:\.|,(?: [Á-ÝA-Z-]\.)+)` would include them.
- Then there are the regular cases with multiple authors separated by `;` (e.g. "ALMEIDA, M.; SOUZA, R.; FONSECA, F."). We can repeat the regular expression for matching a single name (with one or more initials).

  So adding `(?:; [Á-ÝA-Z-][Á-ÝA-Z\s()-]+,(?: [Á-ÝA-Z-]\.)+)*` to the end produces:

  ```
  ^[Á-ÝA-Z-][Á-ÝA-Z\s()-]+(?:\.|,(?: [Á-ÝA-Z-]\.)+)(?:; [Á-ÝA-Z-][Á-ÝA-Z\s()-]+,(?: [Á-ÝA-Z-]\.)+)+
  ```
- At this point we have a few corner cases:

  - "-" in initials: "PLLPEN, P.; KIM, K.-S.;" and "CHEN, P. P-S."
  - Commas separating multiple authors: "GREIMAS, A. J., COURTÉS, J."
  - Having "de" as part of name: "GRACIOSO, L. de S." and "BRUYNE, P. de, HERMAN, J., SCHOUTHEETE, M. de." The latter also uses commas to separate multiple authors.
  - Having "et al" after: "CINTRA, A. et al." and "GONZÁLEZ, J. A. M. et al."
  - "BUFREM, L. S, et al." didn't match for two reasons: There's a typo (missing period after "S") and "et al" isn't recognized. This "et al" is written with a comma before it.

**Matching the title.**

- Starting with a simple pattern, `([^.]+)` grabs most.
- Some corner cases:

  - "Wittgenstein, Language and Information: Back to the Rough Ground!"
  - "FOAF Vocabulary Specification 0.9"
  - "The Entity-Relationship Model-Toward a Unified View of Data. ACM Transactions on Database Systems, v.1, n.1, p. 9-36, 1976"
  - [and so on...](https://regex101.com/r/VyfvI0/1)